# River's Name as an Adjective

Tags: adjectives, names, toponyms, rules

Is there any rule that describes the cases when one can use a river's name as an adjective and when it should be with the *-ian* suffix?

- There is the so-called ***Danubian*** corridor, but it's the ***Danube*** Delta
- There is the *Autonomous **Dniestrian** Territory*, but it's the ***Dniester*** Canyon.
- There is the *Middle **Dnieprian** dialect*, but it's the ***Dnieper*** Upland.

Comment: @Lawrence My question is not a duplicate. There is no information about the _-ian_ suffix.

Comment: Apologies, I misread your question as asking what suffixes (other than *-ian*) you could use. I've retracted my vote regarding the purported duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are completely different things. You use an adjective when you need an adjective. Use a predicate test to know which is which.

In *the Danubian corridor*, you have an actual adjective derived from a noun: the corridor ***is*** Danubian. Hence *Danubian* is an adjective.

In *the Danube delta*, you do not have an adjective at all: the delta **is *not*** Danube. It is the delta **of the** Danube, using a prepositional phrase to connect one noun to another. Hence *Danube* is only ever a noun. It is not an adjective.

You could think of *Danube delta* as a compound noun.

Comment: This doesn't actually explain when to use "Danubian X" vs. "Danube X".

Comment: @sumelic As I understand, the rule is the following: when one talks about the Danube (or any river) itself, one doesn't need to use Danubian. But when it's something related to a river, but not about the river, one should use that adjective. For example, it's the Danube Basin (the basin of the Danube), but it should be the Danubian Republic (this is an imaginary polity), because this entity is not about the river itself, it just would be named after the river.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any real rule, as far as I can tell. The examples given in the question don't actually seem to be exactly right: judging by the [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams), "Danube Delta" is much more common than "Danubian Delta", but "Danubian corridor" doesn't seem to be more common than "Danube corridor". Some of the hits for "Danube Corridor" may be mistakenly picking up things like "Rhine-Danube corridor", but there are definitely examples of "Danube corridor" being used on its own: e.g. "[Introduction to the Spatial Plan of the Danube Corridor Through Serbia](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZANkDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA170)".

We say "Middle Dnieprian dialect" because it is a language variety. Words referring to languages and language varieties tend to take the form of adjectives, regardless of whether they are used as nouns; note that we would also say "a Russian dialect" or "a Ukrainian dialect", not *"a Russia dialect" or *"a Ukraine dialect" (and "Russian" and "Ukrainian" are used alone as nouns meaning "the Russian language" or "the Ukrainian language").